# NodeJS + FB api : Publish images to Page

Tags: node.js, image, upload, facebook-javascript-sdk

I create a script that will post images to my Facebook Page. I follow this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload#upload-file-data but I'm stuck on the last step ... They say I have to put the "file handler" return in the previous step but when I do this I receive an error 100 : Invalid argument ...

This is my code so far :

```
    FB.setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
    var stats = fs.statSync('./generatedSocialPictures/ILiga_260520221800_facebookPicture.png');
    var fileSizeInBytes = stats.size;
    console.log("SIZE OF FILE : " + fileSizeInBytes);
    // Step 1 : get the ID uplaod Session
    var sessionId = await FB.api(
        '/app/uploads',
        'POST',
        {
            'file_length': fileSizeInBytes,
            'file_name': 'ILiga_260520221800_facebookPicture.png',
            'file_type': 'image/png',
            'session_type': 'attachment'
        },
        function(response) {
            if(response.error) {
                console.log(response.error);
                return
            }
            SessionID = response.id
            // Step 2 : Upload the file/image
            FB.api(
                '/'+SessionID,
                'POST',
                {
                    filename: "ILiga_260520221800_facebookPicture.png",
                    contentType: "image/png",
                    value: fs.createReadStream("./generatedSocialPictures/ILiga_260520221800_facebookPicture.png"),
                },
                function(response) {
                    if(response.error) {
                        console.log(response.error);
                        return
                    }
                    // Step 4 : Publish with the file handler in attachment
                    FB.api(
                        '/BetAssistantOfficiel/feed',
                        'POST',
                        { 
                            "image_hash": response.h,
                            "name":"Name for testing",
                            "message": "Testing with api" },
                        function (response) {
                            if (response.error) {
                                console.log('error occurred: ')
                                console.log(response.error)
                                return;
                            }
                            console.log('successfully posted to page!');
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

After severals hours of reading, I found that the process describe earlier was depracated ...

I find a way to this to work :

```
    var filename = generateFacebookPicture(match_informations);
    // Step 1 : upload file to facebook page album
    FB.api(`/{album_id}/photos`, 'POST', 
        {
            'source': fs.createReadStream("PATH_TO_THE_LOCAL_FILE"),
            // 'url': 'URL_OF_THE_IMAGE,
            'caption': "Ceci est un test de publication avec image via api",
            'alt_text_custom': 'Ceci est une alt description',
            //'tag': [{'x':, 'y', 'tag_uid, tag_text'}]
            // 'published': false ==> IF YOU WANT TO PUBLISH LATER
            // 'scheduled_publish_time' ==> DATE OF THE PUBLICATION
        }, 
        function (response) {
            if (response.error) {
                console.log('error occurred: ')
                console.log(response.error)
            } else {
                console.log('local photo uploaded to page!');
                // Step 2 : publish media
                FB.api(
                    '/BetAssistantOfficiel/feed',
                    'POST',
                    { 
                        "object_attachment": response.id,
                        "message": `TODO`,
                        "link": "IF YOU WANT TO",
                        "name": "Bet Assistant - Match XXXXX",
                        "description": "Description",
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.error) {
                            console.log('error occurred: ')
                            console.log(response.error)
                        } else {
                            console.log('successfully posted to page!');
                        }
                    }
                );    
            }
        }
    );
```

Hope this help someone !